# Optimisation involving an extra variable

Tags: mathematical-optimization

Mathematica is happy performing the following optimization:

```
Minimize[{x - Log[x], x > 0}, x]
(* {1, {x -> 1}} *)
```

and also this one involving an extra unspecified variable:

```
Minimize[{(1 + a^2 - x)^2, x > 0}, x]
(* {0, {x -> 1 + a^2}} *)
```

but not the following one:

```
Minimize[{(1 + a^2) x - Log[x], x > 0}, x]
(* Minimize[{(1 + a^2) x - Log[x], x > 0}, x] *)
```

I use `1+a^2` just to provide something that is always positive. The third one should be easy to solve, obtaining a minimum at `x=1/(1+a^2)`. How can I present this sort of problem to Mathematica in a way that it can handle?

Comment: min at `x=1/(1+a^2)`  instead of `x=1+a^2`

Comment: oops, thanks @cvgmt!

Comment: According to `tutorial/ManipulatingEquationsAndInequalities#2489`, `Minimize and Maximize can produce exact symbolic results for polynomial optimization problems with parameters.` I guess `Minimize` can only handle (real) algebraic expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Minimize can't do that for general a, althoug you restict it, but with the trick to insert a numerical value for a ( here: EulerGamma), it works. This means, Minimize knows the neccesary rule, but is not mighty enought to test validity for arbitrary a.

Nevertheless you have to test, whether this procedure is valid for the a range you have in mind.

```
Minimize[{(1 + a^2) x - Log[x], x > 0} /. a -> EulerGamma, x] /. 
  EulerGamma -> a // Simplify

(*   {1 + Log[1 + a^2], {x -> 1/(1 + a^2)}}   *)

(tab = Table[
    Minimize[{(1 + (10^k  EulerGamma)^2) x - Log[x], x > 0}, x] /. 
       EulerGamma -> a/10^k // Apart // FullSimplify, {k, -5, 
     5}]) // TableForm
```